# Why do i get "GET 500" error with AJAX in Wordpress?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to access a table from wpdb but this GET 500 error keeps appearing. If i don't type anything in the year input then it casually prints "year not found", which means that ajax works fine but something's wrong with the $wpdb variable. I tried including the wp-db.php file as you can see but still the problem persists. Can someone help? Thanks in advance!

Here is the php code:

```
<?php

require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-includes/wp-db.php');

$s=(isset($_GET['username']) ? $_GET['username'] : '');
if ( $s != '' ) { 
    //global $wpdb;

    $year = ( isset( $_GET['year'] ) ? $_GET['year'] : '');

    if( $year != '' ) { 

        $results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE year='2019'")); 
        echo $results;
    }
    else { 
        echo "year not found";
    } 
}
else echo "user not exist";
?>
```

Here is the :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="data-container"><input id="year" type="text" name="year" placeholder="Year">
<button onclick="search()">Search</button>
</div>
<script>
function search() {
   $.ajax({
       url: "http://testingforwordpress.epizy.com/get_mylaw.php",
       method:"GET",
       data: { "username": getCookie("usernameCookie"), "year": $("#year").val() }
   }).done(function(data) {
      console.log(data);     
   }); 
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
           return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
</script>
```

Comment: If you go in your browser developer tool ( F12 ), under the network tab, can you check if there is any errors in your request

Comment: Read error logs to find the cause of 500 error.

Comment: I see two different types of superglobals here. Both GET and POST; why is that?

Comment: Yes i am sorry, its not $_POST its $_GET

Comment: Shouldn't the $wpdb variable work since i included the path to wp-db?

Comment: @Nicolas all i see is this "500 Internal Server Error"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of requiring `wp-includes/wp-db.php`, please do

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');
```

, which will fire up WP core along with loading the configuration and database object. wp-db.php isn't meant to be used as an independent submodule that grabs the wp-config.php configuration on its own.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems to have fixed the issue!